# Hausdorff space properties

Tags: general-topology, limits

Prove that in Hausdorff space:

1. $A'$ is always closed
2. $(A')' \subset A'$
3. $(CL(A))' = A'$

Where $A'$ is derived set. Or the set of all the limit points of $A$.

I suposse that definition of $A'$ can help to do first property, but where I use the hypothesis that $V \cap U = \varnothing $. For third I think that every point of Hausdorff space is  closed so they are in the $CL(A)$ but how I can conclude that they are in her limit points. Thank you very much

Comment: What is your definition of $A'$?

Comment: @pisco125 A' is derived set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, these don't require Hausdorff. We only need $T_1$, which is equivalent to having that singletons are closed.

For 1, show that $(A')^c$ is open. That is, fix $x\not\in A'$, find an open neighborhood of $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap A\subseteq\{x\}$. Then $U\subseteq (A')^c$. Indeed, if $y\in U$, then either $y=x\in (A')^c$ or, because the space is $T_1$, the set $U\setminus\{x\}$ is a neighborhood of $y$ that does not intersect $A$. Therefore $(A')^c$ is open.

For 2, let $x\in(A')'$ and fix an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$. By assumption there is $y\in U\cap A'$ that is distinct from $x$. Now use the $T_1$ assumption to obtain a point $z\in U\cap A$ that is distinct from $x$.

For 3, first note that $\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$$\cl(A)'\supseteq A'$ follows easily because $\cl(A)\supseteq A$. For the reverse inclusion, follow a similar argument to parts 1 and 2.

Comment: My edit was for a typo in the last sentence of Part 1: $\;(A')^c$is open for $\;A'$ is open.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you!

Comment: Very good point that the space need only be $T_1$.

Comment: Why $U∩A⊆ {x}$ ?

Comment: @BellaPatarroyo Because $x\not\in A'$. Since $y\in A'$ iff every neighborhood $U$ of $y$ satisfies $U\cap(A\setminus\{y\})\ne\emptyset$, we know that $y\not\in A'$ iff there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $y$ which satisfies $U\cap(A\setminus\{y\})=\emptyset$. This is more nicely written as $U\cap A\subseteq\{y\}$.