# Hausdorff space (derived set)

Tags: general-topology

Prove that in Hausdorff spaces:

- $A'$ is always closed.
- $(A')' \subset A'$
- The closure of $(A')=A'$

I have the following definition for $A'$ but I don't how to use it.
$$A'= \{ x \in X : \forall\text{ open } U \subseteq X\text{ such that }x\in U, ((U\setminus\{x\}) \cap A\ne \emptyset) \}$$
or is there another simpler definition? I know that the points of a Hausdorff space are closed, so are all the points of $A'$ closed too?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: try using the definition of closed set and closure and compare them with the definition you've got of $A'$.

Comment: Your definition of $A'$ does not make much sense to me. $A'=\emptyset$ for every $A$ according to it (which by the way makes trivially true the three statements of yours).

Comment: So, which definition could I use?

Comment: But with these definition or do you use another? I don't have clear how is (A')' ?

Comment: Of course if every point of a space is closed, then every point in A' is closed.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451122/hausdorff-space-properties/2451176#2451176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $A\subseteq X$ any nonempty subset. I will use your definition of $A^{\prime}$.

${\bf (i)}$ $A^{\prime}$ is closed.

To show that $A^{\prime}$ is closed it will suffice to show that $X\setminus A^{\prime}$ is open. Then let $y\in X\setminus A^{\prime}$. Then, by definition, there is an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq X$ that contains $y$ and is such that $(U\setminus\{y\})\cap A=\emptyset$. We then also have that $z\notin A^{\prime}$ for every $z\in U$ because $V:=U\setminus\{y\}$ is an open set containing $z$ and is such that $(V\setminus\{z\})\cap A=\emptyset$. Thus $U$ is completely contained in $X\setminus A^{\prime}$, which is to say that $X\setminus A^{\prime}$ is open and $A^{\prime}$ is closed by virtue of being the complement of an open set.

${\bf (ii)}$ $(A^{\prime})^{\prime}\subseteq A^{\prime}$

Let $x\in (A^{\prime})^{\prime}$ and let $U\subseteq X$ be an open set containing $x$. Then $(U\setminus\{x\})\cap A^{\prime}\neq\emptyset$. Then let $y\in (U\setminus\{x\})\cap A^{\prime}$. Because $V:=U\setminus\{x\}$ is open and contains $y$ we have that $(V\setminus\{y\})\cap A\neq\emptyset$. Thus we have that $(U\setminus\{x\})\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $x\in A^{\prime}$. Therefore $(A^{\prime})^{\prime}\subseteq A^{\prime}$.

${\bf (iii)}$ The closure of $A^{\prime}$ is $A^{\prime}$.

I'm not sure what you are using as your definition for the closure of a set, but usually the closure of a set $B$ is defined to be the intersection of all closed sets containing $B$. In this case we proved in ${\bf (i)}$ that $A^{\prime}$ is closed, so the intersection of all closed sets containing $A^{\prime}$ is the intersection of a collection of sets that all contain $A^{\prime}$, including $A^{\prime}$ itself, so the intersection of this collection is $A^{\prime}$ trivially. In general, the closure of a closed set is always itself.

${\bf Exercise:}$ Where did I invoke the Hausdorff condition?

Comment: Do you use the Hausdorff condition when you define z in the first item?

Comment: No. The condition is used when I define $V$ (why?). A couple of follow up questions might be: Did I really need something as strong as the Hausdorff condition? If the problem was changed so that the space was $T_{1}$ instead of $T_{2}$ (Hausdorff) would my solution still work?

Comment: oh it could be T1 too, the thing is you use an open which does not contain the another element, is it right?

Comment: I'm not sure that I've parsed your comment correctly, but I do believe that the solution is still correct if you weaken the space to being $T_{1}$. My argument needs the set $V$ to be open. It is alright if it's empty.